# Cómo resuelvo Error fetching user by ID en el método show en el controlador de usuarios?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Estoy aprendiendo NODE con el libro Get Programing with Node js de Johnatan Wexler y en lección 19 hago algo que rompé el programa. El error es:

```
Error fetching user by ID: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "new" at path "_id" for model "User"
ERROR occurred: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "new" at path "_id" for model "User"
```

Asumo que el error está en el controlador de usuarios,  puntualmente en el método User.findById(userId)  pero no se como resolverlo,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
  show: (req, res, next) => {
    let userId = req.params.id;//Collect the user ID from the request params
    console.log(userId)//IT BROKES HERE
    User.findById(userId)//Find a user by its ID.
        .then(user => {
          res.locals.user = user;//Pass the user through the response object to the next middleware function.
            next();
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(`Error fetching user by ID: ${error.message}`);
          next(error);//
        });
      },
```

Este es el esquema del modélo:

```
const Subscriber = require("./subscriber");
const mongoose = require("mongoose"),
  {Schema} = mongoose,//Notice the use of object destructuring for the Mongoose Schema object. {Schema} assigns the Schema object in mongoose to a constant by the same name.

  userSchema = new Schema({//Create the user schema
  name: {//Add first and last name properties
    first: {
      type: String,
      trim: true
    },
    last: {
      type: String,
      trim: true
    }
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    lowercase: true,
    unique: true
  },
  zipCode: {
    type: Number,
    min: [1000, "Zip code too short"],
    max: 99999
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },//Add a password property.
  courses: [{type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Course"}],//Add a courses property to connect users to courses.
  subscribedAccount: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:
 "Subscriber"}//Add a subscribedAccount to connect users to subscribers
}, {
  timestamps: true//Add a timestamps property to record createdAt and updatedAt dates
});
```

Me parece que el error es está otra ruta, la cuál es añadida en el material del libro del libro, pero no entiedo porqué corre esta línea y no la ruta *new*

```
router.get("/users/:id", usersController.show, usersController.showView);
```

Comment: Sería útil que añadieras el código de tu esquema de datos y lo que mustra ese `console.log(userId);` que tienes allí. Saludos

Comment: Listo, añadí parte del código que hay en el modelo, alguna idea?

Comment: Pues se ve todo bien, al parecer estás enviando un valor `id` erróneo, qué te muestra el `console.log(req.params.id)` en tu controlador?

Comment: **new**, al parecer no lee la ruta new, interpreta esto como el string new, no entiendo porqué pero supongo que eso será otra pregunta...coño con esto, pero  Muchas grx en verdad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La palabra `new` no es un mongo _id valido.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/ObjectId/

Como estas utilizando mongoose, puedes validar el parametro utilizando `mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(userId)` antes de que llegue a la db

Para crear un _id valido puedes utilizar `mongoose.Types.ObjectId()`

Answer (score 2):

Lo que pasa es que el parámetro `id` que recibís en `req` no es el correcto. Deberías recibir un id pero en cambio estás recibiendo la cadena `new`. Esto ocasiona que tu modelo no encuentre un usuario con id `new`, y por lo tanto se ejecuta la parte en el `catch`. Probablemente esto se debe a que el link al usuario que deseas ver es incorrecto. Podés modificar la url a mano para comprobar que esta parte es correcta, pero después tendrías que revisar que el link para ver el usuario esté bien.